# which offline maps is better for iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, maps, offline

I'm working on iphone application containing offline maps for one city only

I've searched and found mapBox and route me , which is better if I want to drop pins on the map and view information for each pin ?

Can I store google map for one city in the data base and use it ?

Any suggestions for this ?

Comment: Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for what questions to ask and not.

Comment: Probably this could be closed soon, but its interesting. I want to know that too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapBox, RouteMe and even MapKit are capable of displaying offline locally stored maps, the differences between all three is the level of effort required to do so along with their feature sets. Which one to use is totally dependant on what you're trying to achieve. In the past I've used MapKit to display custom maps (raster, PNG format) for selected areas, with the maps sliced into tiles and named similarly to Google tiles such as:

```
/MapTiles/Z<ZoomLevel>/<XCoord>/<YCoord>.png
```

This may help you if you were to use MapKit https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo. As for pins that display information, MapKit is also capable of that.

To compare, you'd more than likely use MapBox if you wanted to apply a custom style to suit your application's appearance, highlighting features that are important to the use of your application.

As for offline storage of Google maps, while you technically can retrieve individual tiles by URL, store them and display them offline (similar to above), this would likely be a violation of their terms of service. An alternative could be to use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).