# Offline maps with routing for a particular place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, offlineapps

I want to present  offline map in my app.How can i implement it...?
I have gone through some of the links but i am not getting it how to start with it.

[How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)

http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/

[which offline maps is better for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097763/which-offline-maps-is-better-for-iphone)

[Route-Me Offline Maps from Document Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155714/route-me-offline-maps-from-document-root)

Please help me to find the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Mapbox is probably perfect for you and has detailed installation instructions. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need just offline maps then go with Open Street Maps. There's [Rout-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) project with demo source. Code examples dowload bitmap tiles from Open Street maps server and caches in sqlite database.

Regarding Mapbox, it does not have offline routing. Routing requires internet. I already did some research several month ago, and I was unable to find any stable offline routing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several stable offline routing systems which use OSM data. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing.